# How can I display a h1 which is centered text with an underline that is smaller than the h1?

Tags: html, css

How can I display a h1 which is centered text with an underline that is smaller than the h1?

Code:
I used the following CSS Code for my H1 Tag that I gave a class:

```
.referenzen{
  display:inline-block;
  position:center; 
}

.referenzen::after{
  content:'';
  height:2px;
  width:20%;
  background:#f24432;
  position:absolute;
  left:calc(50% - 10%);
  bottom:-5px;

}
```

the problem: the H1 isnt centered.

Thank you!

Comment: `position:center;` is wrong: you probably want `text-align:center;` and `position:relative;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer using flex as display so you can use justify content to center your content unlike the other answer posted.

```css
.referenzen{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.referenzen::after{
  content:'';
  height:2px;
  width:20px;
  background:#f24432;
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  bottom:-5px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="referenzen">Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `position: relative;` and `text-align: center;`. There is no `center` value for `position` property.

```css
.referenzen{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.referenzen::after{
  content:'';
  height:2px;
  width:20%;
  background:#f24432;
  position:absolute;
  left:calc(50% - 10%);
  bottom:-5px;

}
```

```html
<h1 class="referenzen">Title</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! But the text is still not on the middle of the Webpage if I use it like this